# How to make a grid of histograms in pandas with a common graph in all of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

Is there a way to use the pandas.DataFrame.hist() function to create a grid of histograms, where each graph contains a specific variable, as well as a common variable in all of them? For example, in the following DataFrame, I'd like to have depth to be graphed with length in one of them, and with width in the other.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'length': [1.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 3, 0.4, 0.2],
     'width': [0.7, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 1.1, 0.2, 0.1],
     'depth': [1, 0.4, 0.5, 1.1, 2, 0.1, 0.9]
     }, index= ['pig', 'rabbit', 'duck', 'chicken', 'horse', 'cow', 'dog'])
hist = df.hist(bins=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to re-draw the histogram again:

```
# draw the histograms for other columns except `depth`
axes = df.drop('depth',axis=1).hist(bins=3)

# draw histogram for `depth` in each of the subplots
for ax in axes.flat:
    df['depth'].hist(bins=3, ax=ax, alpha=0.7)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I accepted your answer but the behavior is weird, the y axes are scaled in a weird way, but thanks!